# Find all characteristic subgroups of the Dihedral group $D_{12}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups, characteristic-subgroups

In my notation $$D_{12}=\langle \rho,\tau : \rho^6=\tau^2=1,\ \rho \tau \rho=\tau\rangle$$
So firstly, I know that all characteristic subgroups are normal. Thus, the possible candidates of $D_{2n}$ for the characteristic subgroups are $$\{1\},D_{12},<\rho>,<\rho^2>,<\rho^3>,<\rho^2,\tau>,<\rho^2,\rho\tau>$$
Is there now a property or tool which I can use to pick out the characteristic subgroups. I know for sure that $D_{12}$ and $\{1\}$ as well as the commutator subgroup $D_{12}'=<\rho>$ are characteristics, but what about the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, consider the orders of the subgroups. If there is only one subgroup of a certain order, surely it must be characteristic. Of the three remaining subgroups, only one is cyclic, and so it must also be characteristic. For the remaining two groups, it is not hard to check whether there is an automorphism mapping one to the other.

Comment: Can you help me to list the elements of the subgroup of $<\rho^2,\rho \tau>$. It's all possibgle products of $\rho ^2$ and $\rho \tau$, right?

Comment: Yes, it is. And I'm sure you can list them yourself, there are only six elements.

Comment: I gor $<\rho^2,\rho \tau >=\{1,\rho^2,\rho^4,\rho \tau, \rho^3\tau, \rho^5\tau\}$

Comment: So, since $<\rho^2>,<\rho^3> and <\rho^2,\tau>$ have respectively orders 3,2 and 5, they are characterstics. I just need to check for the last one?

Comment: The first two groups; yes. The group $\langle\rho^2,\tau\rangle$ does not have order 5. In general, the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot $\rho^4$, so it's also of order 6?

Comment: Yes. So you just need to check whether the last two subgroups are characteristic. Note that they are either both characteristic, or both not characteristic. After all, if one is not characteristic, there must be an automorphism that maps it to another subgroup, which must then be the other.

Answer (score 1):

As for the remaining $2$ subgroups,  $\langle \rho^2,\tau\rangle$ and $\langle \rho^2,\rho\tau\rangle$ there is an automorphism of $D_{12}$ sending them to each other...  Namely, the one determined by $\rho\to\rho$ and $\tau\to\rho\tau$.  (By the relation $\rho\tau\rho=\tau$, the elements $\tau$ and $\rho\tau$ both have order $2$;  or, they are both reflections.)

So, these two subgroups aren't characteristic...